# Filtering w/ AWK

Tags: shell, unix, awk, header, filtering

Hello I am a bit new with coding so sorry if this does not make sense.  I need help with a script I am trying to work on for a file.  The file is comma delimited and would like to filter it to only show specific character and also keep it's header.   I am trying to filter the file by collateral codes which is in field 10 and I have over 2000 records on this file.

```
Example:
Name, Address, Phone, Zip, Coll Code, 
Susan Mary, abc, 12345678, 12345, T, etc..
Jon Doe, abc, 12345678, 12345, Y, etc..
Carry Mclaughlin, abc, 12345678, 12345, T, etc..
Larry Burk, abc, 12345678, 12345, M, etc..

Wanted Output:

Name, Address, Phone, Zip, Coll Code, etc.. 
Susan Mary, abc, 12345678, 12345, T, etc..
Carry Mclaughlin, abc, 12345678, 12345, T, etc..
```

here's the sample I am currently using (code is in field 10).

```
awk -F, '{if ($10 == "T") print $0}' originalfile > newfile
```

Only problem I am having right now is keepign the HEADER on this file.

-Thank you

Comment: but `T` is not the 10th column in your input

Comment: Well the example i gave you was just a quick sample, but in the actual file it is in the 10th column.  I figured out what I needed to add to include the header.

Comment: Please don't show us one thing and then tell us "I know that doesn't make sense given what I've shown you but with a different file only I can see this does make sense...." - simply [edit] your question so it makes sense stand-alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question but it **sounds** like this might be what you want:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 || $10=="T"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

okay so took me an hour to finally figure this one out.  Here is the command i used

```
awk -F, 'NR==1; NR > 1{if ($10 == "T") print $0}' originalfile > newfile
```

Comment: That is one crazy command line :-). You can learn awk from the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: This is a more verbose, less idiomatic way of writing Ed Morton's solution.